# WPF - the button doesn't recognise its icon path

Tags: wpf, xaml

Why doesn't it recognise the path, even though the icon is entered in the project as well?

[image]

Comment: Make sure the Build Action of the image file is set to Resource.

Comment: could you write an specific example please?

Comment: Of what? Setting the Build Action of a file on your Visual Studio project? Take a look at the context menu on the file.

Comment: Right-click on the image file and in the drop-down menu click properties then you can see Build action of the file in the properties window check it is resource or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether your image file is added as Resource.

Right-click on the image file in the drop-down menu and select Properties.

[image: Properties]

Then in the properties window make sure the Build Action is set to Resource.

[image]